# Fetch data using column names stored as values in a column within the same dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, loops, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large dataset similar to example below :

| ID | CODE | STUDY | AMOUNT | COL_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 5611 | ABCD | 56.17 | ID |
| 211 | 5411 | GFED | 451.1 | AMOUNT |
| 311 | 3212 | YTRA | 687.3 | STUDY |

I want to populate the values of the columns stored in col_name in a column(COL_VAL) within the same dataframe as below :

| ID | CODE | STUDY | AMOUNT | COL_NAME | COL_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 5611 | ABCD | 56.17 | ID | 111 |
| 211 | 5411 | GFED | 451.1 | AMOUNT | 451.1 |
| 311 | 3212 | YTRA | 687.3 | STUDY | YTRA |

I am using a loop and .collect() to populate values but it is taking a lot of time. Would like to know efficient ways to do same relevant for a large dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) to achieve this.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(111, 5611, "ABCD", 56.17, "ID",),
(211, 5411, "GFED", 451.1, "AMOUNT",),
(311, 3212, "YTRA", 687.3, "STUDY",),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("ID", "CODE", "STUDY", "AMOUNT","COL_NAME"))

def derive_column_value():
    condition = F
    for possible_value in df.columns:
        condition = condition.when(F.col("COL_NAME") == possible_value, F.col(possible_value))
    return condition

df.withColumn("COL_VALUE", derive_column_value()).show()
```

### Output

```
+---+----+-----+------+--------+---------+
| ID|CODE|STUDY|AMOUNT|COL_NAME|COL_VALUE|
+---+----+-----+------+--------+---------+
|111|5611| ABCD| 56.17|      ID|      111|
|211|5411| GFED| 451.1|  AMOUNT|    451.1|
|311|3212| YTRA| 687.3|   STUDY|     YTRA|
+---+----+-----+------+--------+---------+
```